# Kafka consumer group keep moving to PreparingRebalance state and stops consuming

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

We have a Kafka Streams consumer group that keep moving to PreparingRebalance state and stop consuming.
The pattern is as follows:

1. Consumer group is running and stable for around 20 minutes
2. New consumers (members) start to appear in the group state without any clear reason, these new members only originate from a small number of VMs (not the same VMs each time), and they keep joining
3. Group state changes to PreparingRebalance
4. All consumers stop consuming, showing these logs:
   "Group coordinator ... is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery"
5. The consumer on VMs that generated extra members show these logs:

> Offset commit failed on partition X at offset Y: The coordinator is not aware of this member.
>
> Failed to commit stream task X since it got migrated to another thread already. Closing it as zombie before triggering a new rebalance.
>
> Detected task Z that got migrated to another thread. This implies that this thread missed a rebalance and dropped out of the consumer group. Will try to rejoin the consumer group.

6. We kill all consumer processes on all VMs, the group moves to Empty with 0 members, we start the processes and we're back to step 1

Kafka version is 1.1.0, streams version is 2.0.0

We took thread dumps from the misbehaving consumers, and didn't see more consumer threads than configured.

We tried restarting kafka brokers, cleaning zookeeper cache.

We suspect that the issue has to do with missing heartbeats, but the default heartbeat is 3 seconds and message handling times are no where near that.

Anyone encountered a similar behaviour?

Comment: This behavior, especially the `Group coordinator is unavailable or invalid...` log message, indicates your Kafka consumers heartbeat is timing out.  This is often due to memory pressure and long GC pauses.  Have you tried profiling the JVM to understand the memory usage of your app?

Comment: What do you mean by `New consumers (members) start to appear in the group state without any clear reason,`? Can it be that there is an independent application that (by accident) uses the same `application.id` as yours?

Comment: @ck1 not yet, but that's a good direction. Thanks!

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax We made sure that's not the case. Also, we found the source of the new members to be in some of the VMs where consumers are running.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I see a similar behaviour with Kafka 2.4.1 & clients on 2.4.1 as well. The consumer group state moves to 'Preparing Rebalance' after consuming data for few hours or even a day. Very unpredictable behaviour

Comment: We are facing the same problem here, the consumers works fine for around 10 minutes or so and then all consumers stops consuming. We have four servers, this behaviour is with our production server, pre prod and staging are working fine. @avshalomman did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @AshwaniGarg we eventually found that a few consumers were stuck (randomly), causing very long lags in their partitions.
Therefore when restarted the consumers that "received" these very delayed partitions were bombarded and couldn't keep up.
We then fixed the issue that caused consumers to hang randomly, and truncated all consumers to read from the end of the stream (latest). Hope that makes sense

Comment: In my case, it was due to a mis-modification of a poll loop \ 
-- I accidentally **create a new `consumer` every time in the inf poll loop**. \ 
1. before-correct: `while (true) { consumer.poll(` \ 
2. after-wrong: `while (true) { consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(prop); consumer.subscribe(XXX); consumer.poll(`